# How to switch between scenes in Sprite Kit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

What's wrong with my code? Every time I hit the button I'm getting a default grey screen. Button for transition:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.pause {
            var pauseScene = PauseScene(size: self.size)
            scene?.paused = true
            let skView = self.view as SKView!
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            pauseScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            pauseScene.size = skView.bounds.size
            skView.presentScene(pauseScene)
        }
    }
}
```

What I have in that scene that don't want to load:

```
class PauseScene: SKScene {
    let pauseBackground = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "pauseBackground")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.pauseBackground.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.pauseBackground.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(pauseBackground)
    }

}
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your issue is in `didMoveToView:` in your PauseScene. You don't want to change your anchor point for `self.pauseBackground` Normally anchor point is based on 0 to 1. (.5,.5) being the center of the sprite. You are setting it to something much higher than that and if you are setting the position to half the width and hight of the scene I don't see why you would want to change the anchor point at all. Looks like just deleting the line of code should fix the issue.

```
class PauseScene: SKScene {
let pauseBackground = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "pauseBackground")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.pauseBackground.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(pauseBackground)
    }
}
```

Also I see you are changing the size of your scene after you init it. I would just init it with the size you want.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.pause {
            let skView = self.view as SKView!
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            var pauseScene = PauseScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
            scene?.paused = true
            pauseScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            skView.presentScene(pauseScene)
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps and makes sense.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I don't know, I thought it makes sense. Like if I make anchor point in the center and position it at the center – it would cover all screen. I really am experiencing troubles with positioning sprites and don't know where to look information about it. For example I thought that middle of a scene is (x:0.5, y:0,5) so if I want to put my sprite a bit lower I need to do (x:0.5, y:0.4). But when I try that it always looks horrible and I don't know why. But thanks again!

Comment: @Burundanga you are welcome and I feel your pain. Position is always done in points and it can be confusing. Your scene bottom left is (0,0) and top right is (scene.width, scene.height). Rule of thumb never change anchor unless you are looking for a desired effect (ex. rotate sprite around top left corner).  If you add a child to a node its position is always based on the origin (anchor) of its parent. So without changing any anchors it will be in the center of its parent (on top of its anchor). But anchor is 0-1 not in points. Hopefully that didn't add to the confusion. =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated answer swift 5, iOS 14 Using swiftUI

import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var switcher = false

var scene: SKScene {
    let scene = GameScene.shared
    scene.size = CGSize(width: 256, height: 256)
    scene.scaleMode = .fill
    scene.backgroundColor = .red
    scene.name = "red"
    return scene
}

var scene2: SKScene {
    let scene2 = GameScene2.shared
    scene2.size = CGSize(width: 256, height: 256)
    scene2.scaleMode = .fill
    scene2.backgroundColor = .blue
    scene2.name = "blue"
    return scene2
}

var body: some View {
  if switcher {
    SpriteView(scene: scene)
        .frame(width: 256, height: 256)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .background(Color.red)
        .onAppear {
          scene2.isPaused = true
        }
        .onDisappear {
          scene2.isPaused = false
        }
        
  } else {
    SpriteView(scene: scene2)
        .frame(width: 256, height: 256)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .background(Color.blue)
        .onAppear {
          scene.isPaused = true
        }
        .onDisappear {
          scene.isPaused = false
        }
        
  }
  Button {
    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
      switcher.toggle()
    }
  } label: {
    Text("switch")
  }
}
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

static var shared = GameScene()

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
// Tells your app to perform any app-specific logic to update your scene.
  print("name ",scene!.name)
}
}
```